What tool is this?
Found this in a box of tools from my dad's garage. It has a clamp to secure it to a table and then a 360 clamp that looks like it could hold a dowel or something similar. Anyone know what this is and what it's used for?




Just wondering if it is only one half of something/it holds a tool?  Is there something that would tighten/lock a rod in that hole/does the thumb screw go into the hole also?

Does look like an adjustable base for something. No idea what.

miniature flagpole holder for patriotic workbenches.

My thought is, that it is not a complete tool, there is a part missing that goes in the hole. If the hole had a thumb screw or something similar to hold an object to make it more "universal" would be one thing, but the hole is such that is for a preset item that as made to go in there. And it is not.

Yes, hadn't thought of a missing part. Seems like in absence of something obvious to pair it with, it's mostly likely junk now.

Likely the base for an articulating desk lamp…


I believe that is the base for an articulating vice.
Modern articulating vice


Looks a bit small to me to be a vice mount

Right click might bring up a "copy image" option.  The link is not opening for me.  More my settings than bad link.

I had to look at the page source, but I was able to grab the image

@UES, thanks for posting the image.  I'm not "techy" enough.  I copied the image then when I added, I got a message such as "Not a viable file.Cannot download"  ? Who knows?    I had a vice that was mounted on a post that went into a bench clamp like that.  It was only good for small stuff.
